# Select all rows programmatically UITableView iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView`, I need to implement **Select All** functionality, what I have done is to select all rows programmatically by this way:

```
[self loopTableView:self.tableView2 aiAccesoryType:1];//Checkmark

-(void)loopTableView: (UITableView*) tableView aiAccesoryType: (int) aiAccesoryType
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
                NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                //Here is your code
                if(aiAccesoryType == 1)
                {
                    //Selected
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                    [cell setBackgroundColor:mf_selectedColor];
                }
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            }
    }
}
```

But what I need to achieve is to select all rows as iOS does when you tap a row, no matter if there is no accessory type included at selection
And also I want to get the really selected items to later set a description in each selected row

Comment: Do not do what you are doing here. Instead, update your data model to indicate all rows are selected, then reload the table view. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should setup the cell appropriately based on whether the data model indicates the row is selected or not.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy So, I need to add something as an array that holds the selected items and update it matching the tableView Selection?

Comment: You should already have an array of some data structure/class for your data source. Just add a `BOOL` to that.

Comment: That's it!, but how to selectThisRow at index appropriately inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: `UITableViewCell` has a `selected`property.  Set that to `YES`

Comment: Hmmm I have added `cell.selected = YES;` but scrolling the `tableView` I can see the rows quickly appearing and disappearing its selection, but the rows are not holding the selection

Comment: Something wrong in your cellForRow method surely. Put the code in.